# Taylor expansion with several variables

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

It is known that for $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,

$$f(a + h) = f(a) + f'(a)h + O(h^2)$$

Is there a similar expression for $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? i.e., something like

$$f(a+h) = f(a) + \nabla f(a) \cdot h + O(\|h\|^2)$$

Thanks.

Comment: Of course there is: check the section "generalizations" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem

Comment: @b00nheT. Thanks, but the error term there is not exactly related to $\|h\|$, but also includes terms of the form $h_i h_j$. Does it mean that the answer to my question is no?

Comment: Under assumption that lim h -> 0 it should be true, otherwise not.